# Pulling wire through Sealtight/LiquidTight?

Tags: wiring, conduit, hot-tub

I'm going to make my final run from my 50 amp hot tub panel disconnect to the hot tube using about 20' of 3/4" Sealtight/LiquidTight.

Is there a best way to pull 4 #6 wires through this type of conduit? I assume probably a fish tape would be my best option.

Comment: Using anything you have on hand, like a vacuum cleaner and a string (or a fish tape). I'm not sure what problem you're facing.

Answer (score 2):

I use fish tapes for long flex pulls.

Tapes make the job easier.

As it is a snug fill it probably a bit tough for a novice to do a push but if you tape the ends together tightly and do not tangle the conductors push a foot and as pushing twist the flex.

with each push have the flex out straight and if it starts to bind a snapping action like a bull whip (but not as extreme).

it will usually go you may need to straighten the piece out and continue until the end comes out

With the end put that end on and finish pulling the wires through then connect the ends I do this all the time without a tape but use a tape if it won’t go.

I don’t waste time blowing or sucking “a mouse” through the flex. Note that a mouse is the trade name of pulling a string through pipe and they don’t work well in flex because of the ribs.

Answer (score 1):

Hollow braided rope, by preference - usually polypropylene, but just because that's the most common hollow braided rope around.

Vacuum it in, or vacuum a string in and pull the rope in with the string.

Expand the braid to go over your wires, and stagger the ends of the wires by a few inches so the attachment tapers, as opposed to the "lump" you get when all 4 wires are lined up exactly. Tape the rope end to the wire bundle throughly with good electrical tape.

Alternatively, you can buy a **pulling grip** which is essentially a short section of metal braid with a loop to tie or splice your pulling rope to.

20 feet of liquidtight (at 37+% fill) will probably be a miserable pull. You'll likely want a quart of pulling lube (only use AFTER the taping on is complete)

A fish tape does nothing particularly useful for you, and is harder to grab than rope. You can use one, but I don't recommend it.

Having someone else push as you pull is helpful, (they can also apply more pulling lube as needed.)

Comment: Gotta agree completely with Ecnerwal. Suck a rope thru with a shop vac and tape up the wires like he said.  I've found it helpful to tape something like a thin disposable shopping bag to give the vacuum more surface area to grab onto.   I've used fish tapes before and really don't like them....much prefer a rope. A pulling grip also works well...it's like a Chinese finger trap!

Comment: As a pro I would disagree if you are having trouble pulling with a tape and that nice big plastic housing a string or rope will shred your hands and flex is difficult even with the correct tool to suck a line through compared to a tape , but I would probably push it any way.